# Custom spring property source does not resolve placeholders in @Value

Tags: spring, properties, apache-zookeeper

I'm trying to build a Spring 3.1 PropertySource which reads its values from Zookeeper nodes. For connecting to Zookeeper I am using [Curator](https://github.com/netflix/curator) from Netflix.

For that I've built a custom property source which reads the value of a property from Zookeeper and returns it. This works fine when I am resolving the property like this

```
ZookeeperPropertySource zkPropertySource = new ZookeeperPropertySource(zkClient);
ctx.getEnvironment().getPropertySources().addLast(zkPropertySource);
ctx.getEnvironment().getProperty("foo"); // returns 'from zookeeper'
```

However, when I try to instantiate a bean which has a field with an @Value annotation then this fails:

```
@Component
public class MyBean {
    @Value("${foo}") public String foo;
}

MyBean b = ctx.getBean(MyBean.class); // fails with BeanCreationException
```

This problem has most likely nothing to do with Zookeeper but with the way I'm registering the property sources and creating the beans.

Any insight is highly appreciated.

**Update 1:**

I'm creating the app context from an XML file like this:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ConfigurableApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");
        ctx.registerShutdownHook();
    }
}
```

The class which connects to Zookeeper is a @Component.

```
@Component
public class Server {
    CuratorFramework zkClient;

    public void connectToZookeeper() {
        zkClient = ... (curator magic) ...
    }

    public void registerPropertySource() {
        ZookeeperPropertySource zkPropertySource = new ZookeeperPropertySource(zkClient);
        ctx.getEnvironment().getPropertySources().addLast(zkPropertySource);
        ctx.getEnvironment().getProperty("foo"); // returns 'from zookeeper'
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void start() {
        connectToZookeeper();
        registerPropertySource();
        MyBean b = ctx.getBean(MyBean.class);
    }
}
```

**Update 2**

This seems to work when I'm using XML-less configuration, i.e. @Configuration, @ComponentScan and @PropertySource in combination with an AnnotationConfigApplicationContext. Why doesn't it work with a ClassPathXmlApplicationContext?

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.goleft")
@PropertySource({"classpath:config.properties","classpath:version.properties"})
public class AppConfig {
    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

**Answering to your Update 2:** This does not work with your original configuration(registering a PropertySource using `@PostConstruct`) because the PropertySource is being registered very late, by this time your target bean has already been constructed and initialized.

Typically the injection of the placeholders happens via a [BeanFactoryPostProcessor](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/BeanFactoryPostProcessor.html) which is very early in the Spring lifecycle(beans have not been created at this stage) and if a PropertySource is registered at that stage, then placeholders should be resolved.

The best approach though is to use a [ApplicationContextInitializer](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/ApplicationContextInitializer.html), get a handle on the applicationContext and to register the propertySource there:

```
public class CustomInitializer implements ApplicationContextInitializer<ConfigurableWebApplicationContext> {
    public void initialize(ConfigurableWebApplicationContext ctx) {
        ZookeeperPropertySource zkPropertySource = new ZookeeperPropertySource(zkClient);
        ctx.getEnvironment().getPropertySources().addFirst(zkPropertySource);
    }
}
```

Comment: I've simplified the problem but now I can't get it to work anymore. It always loads from the config file. Well, actually it does work in my non-simplified project but only with the AppConfig class and when the property does not exist in the config.properties file. How do I use the ApplicationContextInitializer with a non-webapp?

Comment: Yes, you are right, it works a little different. I have sent you a pull request to your repository with a test which behaves consistently for annotation and xml based application context.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that works and clean code btw. The catch is that for the ClasspathXmlApplicationContext you have to set ignore-unresolvable="false" in context:property-placeholder. Otherwise it will fail.